# EF6 foreign key constraint in simple model

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, asp.net-mvc-5, virtual, dbset

I am coding a simple MVC 5 internet application. Here are my models:

```
public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> rooms { get; set; }
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item item { get; set; }

    public House()
    {
        rooms = new List<Room>();
    }
}

public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int roomNumber { get; set; }

    public int houseId { get; set; }
    public virtual House house { get; set; }

    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

When I load the Index action result in the House controller, I am getting this error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Rooms_dbo.Items_itemId' on table 'Rooms' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Can I please have some help to code this correctly?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have now added the `ForeignKey` attribute to the fields foreign key fields:

```
public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> rooms { get; set; }
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("itemId")]
    public virtual Item item { get; set; }

    public House()
    {
        rooms = new List<Room>();
    }
}

public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int roomNumber { get; set; }

    public int houseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("houseId")]
    public virtual House house { get; set; }

    public int itemId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("itemId")]
    public virtual Item item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I am still getting the same error.

Comment: How many ID's do you need, ItemId and Item with a property of Id in the Room object.

Comment: ItemId is for the Item object and the Id is the primary key for the whole Room object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I needed to disable cascading deletes in the context class.

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.item)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
        .HasRequired(s => s.item)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```